# how to run batch file from C# in the background

Tags: c#

How can I run a batch file from C# but in the backgound without the command prompt windows being displayed.

I use this Process.Start(batch.bat"); but this will display the command prompt.

Any idea?

Answer (score 15):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
  ProcessStartInfo si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
  si.CreateNoWindow = true;
  si.FileName = "setSecDLL.bat";
  si.UseShellExecute = false;
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(si);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that with a Startinfo:

```
var si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.FileName = "test.cmd";           
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( si);
```