# How to embed a batch file into a c# application

Tags: c#, wcf, batch-file

I have a WCF Service that will execute a batch file. However, I don't want that batch file to be visible/editable by the user. Is there any way I can embed the batch file code into my service (perhaps in a method).

Currently I am using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myBatchFileName);
```

to launch my .bat file but as I mentioned, is visible to users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271938/how-to-run-batch-file-from-c-sharp-in-the-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here explaining how to execute individual Windows shell commands through C#, without having to create/open a batch file:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295585/2661795

I've successfully used this method to execute multiple commands in a row, effectively mimicking the functionality of a batch file without having to expose a batch file to the user.